# How to update product.quantity in PrestaShop with PrestaSharp?

Tags: prestashop

I'm using prestaSharp for C#. I need to update the product quantity but `product.quantity` property is  `readonly`.

```
var ProductFactory = new Bukimedia.PrestaSharp.Factories.ProductFactory(BaseUrl, Account, Password);
List<Bukimedia.PrestaSharp.Entities.product> products = ProductFactory.GetAll();
foreach (var item in myItems)
{
    var productToUpdate = products.First(x => x.reference == item.Ref);
    // update the quantities
    if (productToUpdate != null)
    {
        productToUpdate.quantity = item.Quantity;
    }
}
await ProductFactory.UpdateListAsync(products);
```

How should i proceed? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on that [github reply](https://github.com/Bukimedia/PrestaSharp/issues/347#issue-426382086) i was able to convert the VB code, and update all the stocks in a single call

```
var ProductFactory = new Bukimedia.PrestaSharp.Factories.ProductFactory(BaseUrl, Account, Password);
var StockAvailableFactory = new Bukimedia.PrestaSharp.Factories.StockAvailableFactory(BaseUrl, Account, Password);

// call prestasharp/api/Products to get the products
List<Bukimedia.PrestaSharp.Entities.product> products = ProductFactory.GetAll();

var stocksToUpdate = new List<Bukimedia.PrestaSharp.Entities.stock_available>();
foreach (var itemQ in itemsQuantity)
{
    var productToUpdate = products.First(x => x.reference == itemQ.Ref);
    // update the quantities
    if (productToUpdate != null)
    {
        var dtnSearch = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dtnSearch.Add("id_product", productToUpdate.id.ToString());
        var currentStock = await StockAvailableFactory.GetByFilterAsync(dtnSearch, null, null);
        if(0 < currentStock.Count())
        {
            currentStock[0].quantity = Decimal.ToInt32(itemQ.Quantity);
            stocksToUpdate.Add(currentStock[0]);
        }
    }
}
await StockAvailableFactory.UpdateListAsync(stocksToUpdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop has another table for quantities: "Stock"

You have to use this table and related classes. Something like this:

```
StockAvailable::setQuantity($id_product, $id_product_attribute, $quantity);
```

Comment: i'm not familiar with your sintax, and i don't have a 'setQuantity' method, i can only use the apis, so update/updateList etc, anyway i figured it out